# retrieve the full list of text in isolated storage Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, string, isolatedstorage

I am trying to retrieve multiple images and text through data binding, but I only manage to retrieve only the first text in isolated storage(code below).

Is it possible to retrieve multiple text through data binding into a ListBox?

```
string imageFileName = App.imagePath;

string a;

object b;
sting h;

int i;
string noteSeparate;

private void Library_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{


    if (MainListBox.Items.Count == 0)
    {

        //To save the separated note by '^'
        string[] noteSeparated;
        //Read the file and display it line by line.
        IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        //Read the note saved in myFile.txt
        StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ViewFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore));

            try
            {

                String fileText = readFile.ReadLine();
                //noteSeparated is the variable that save the retrieve note from myFile.txt and is noteSeparated by '^'
                noteSeparated = fileText.Split(new char[] { '^' });

                for (i = 0; i < noteSeparated.Length; i = i + 3)
                {
                  noteSeparate = noteSeparated[i];
                  a = noteSeparate;
                  break;
                }

                h = a;
                readFile.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                noNoteBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        string imageFolder = "imageFolder";

        var isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        // Check if directory exists
        if (!isoFile.DirectoryExists(imageFolder))
        {
            //isoFile.CreateDirectory(imageFolder);
            throw new Exception("Image directory not found");
        }

        ObservableCollection<Items> LibraryItems = new ObservableCollection<Items>();
        // Get files
        foreach (string fileName in isoFile.GetFileNames())
        {
            //string filePath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, imageFileName);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, fileName);
            using (var imageStream = isoFile.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var imageSource = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(imageStream);

                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

                ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
                bi.SetSource(imageStream);
                item.Content = new Image() { Source = bi, MaxHeight = 100, MaxWidth = 100, Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 20) };
                //MainListBox.Items.Add(item);
                b = bi;

            }
            LibraryItems.Add(new Items(b, h));
            MainListBox.ItemsSource = LibraryItems;
        }
}
```

Can anyone help me retrieving all the text saved in isolated storage. **The text in isolated file is in the format of "noteTitle^note^imagePath^noteTitle^note^imagePath^...."** and so on.. I am trying to retrieve all the noteTitle only.

Can anyone help me with getting all the **noteTitle only**?

Answer (score 0):

With `Regex`:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ViewFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore)))
{
    var text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var titles = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<title>[^\^]+)\^(?<note>[^\^]+)\^(?<imagePath>[^\^]+)")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(arg => arg.Groups["title"])
        .ToList();
}
```

or with `Split`

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ViewFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore)))
{
    var text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var i = 0;
    var titles = text.Split('^').Where(arg => i++ % 3 == 0).ToList();
}
```

---

**[EDIT]** To bind the list to the `ListBox`:

```
private void Library_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("ViewFolder\\myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, myStore)))
    {
        var text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var i = 0;
        MainListBox.ItemsSource = text.Split('^').Where(arg => i++ % 3 == 0).ToList();
    }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

Replace this piece of code:

```
String fileText = readFile.ReadLine();
//noteSeparated is the variable that save the retrieve note from myFile.txt and is noteSeparated by '^'
noteSeparated = fileText.Split(new char[] { '^' });
for (i = 0; i < noteSeparated.Length; i = i + 3)
{
    noteSeparate = noteSeparated[i];
    a = noteSeparate;
    break;
}
h = a;
```

with:

```
var fileText = readFile.ReadToEnd();
var i = 0;
var titles = fileText .Split('^').Where(arg => i++ % 3 == 0).ToList();
```

`titles` will be a list of the `notTitle`.

Comment: @ben tan - not sure I understand the question. You asked how to get  the list of `noteTile`. In my code `titles` will contain this list.

Comment: ya i only want to get the title only.. den how can i use this list to retrieve all the titles inside?

Comment: @ben tan - you just set `ItemsSource`. Updated the answer

Comment: hmm but i not sure how to change my code to your answer that is with split

Comment: @ben tan - I thought you are going to get rid of 'image code'. You need to clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: ok for image i need it.. And for my library items variable (h) is to retrieve all the noteTitle.. Because for now my variable (h) only return me the first noteTitle. I would need to retrieve all the noteTitle in the list
sorry

Comment: then for the LibraryItems.Add(new Items(b, h)); 
h change to titles?